# Wordpress enqueue style

Tags: css, wordpress

I've added the following code in functions.php but it doesn't seem to work. What is wrong?

```
function include_styles(){
    wp_enqueue_style ( 'main-style', get_theme_file_uri('/style.css'));
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'include_styles');
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use `get_template_directory_uri()` instead of `get_theme_file_uri`